# Flow Finish Location using Process builder

Tags: flow, visual-workflow

I have Created a flow to generate order from quote, when the quote status changes to Accepted. Flow is invoked using process builder on quote obj, when quote Status is Accepted the flow will trigger and create an order.

Problem is order gets created on quote page. I want the finish location to be new order page. Is there a way to set finish location in process builder or flows?

Comment: I think you'll need some screens on your flow. It sounds like you are using a headless flow that doesn't have any screens to it and is just being used to call up the process builder to do the action. The process runs in the background and then finishes. Without a screen to pop back to I'm not sure how you can customize it from the process builder. 

Alternatively, if you made your process into a APEX class you could execute the logic and have it redirect to any page you want.

Comment: Agree w Dan. Change so you have to use the flow to set order status to accepted (or click a button), and then you can set the finish location. It's a bit tricky to set finish location to a record created by the flow, believe it requires some code, much easier to set it to the record from which you called the flow, but that isn't what you are after.  Will try to dig up some posts on setting finish location.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Dan and Gorav.  The design does not allow me to add a button for this requirement. So i just used Process builder. Is there any other way out apart from process builder to invoke this flow and set the finish location.

Comment: With a flow invoked by a button it is possible to wrap it in a VisualForce page and set the finish location there. I'm not sure if it is possible with a headless flow called by Process Builder.

Comment: There is no way to set a finish location from a headless flow and/or process builder.  The only way is to have a VisualFlow be embeded in a VF page.  Therefore the only way the requirement can be accomplish is using APEX from your process builder.